# How do I Render a background image url for Flask App?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I built a simple Flask app and I'm trying to set a background image from an url. I followed the examples from nuemrous sites but the image is still not rendering. I also have a separate html file called notes I'm trying to link to the initial HTML page that is also not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Desktop\Heart_Disease_APP\templates\HD.css">

<h1>Heart Disease Prediction</h1>

    <body>
```

HD.css:

```
body{
    background-image: url("https://3l4jojspj4-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/iStock- 
    921951792.jpg")
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:160px;
padding-left:280px;
padding-top:50px;
width:470px;
color: #eaeaea;
border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;
}

br{
text-align: right;
}



    <ul>
        <form  method="GET">
        <li><a href="Notes.html">Click Here for Notes</a>
        <br>
    </ul>
```

Comment: In you html file try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('templates', filename='HD.css')}}" `. By the way it is not recommended to keep css and js files in templates folder. You should keep them in `static` folder

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your css, that is in the `background-image` property. First the **closing tag** `;` after closing the `background-image`. Second the `url` has spaces, so path throws an error. Correct the code to this one:

```css
body{
background-image: url("https://3l4jojspj4-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/iStock-921951792.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:160px;
padding-left:280px;
padding-top:50px;
width:470px;
color: #eaeaea;
border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```